# Gaussian curvature of Hyperbolic plane $\mathbb{H}^2=\{x^2+y^2-z^2=-1\}$

Tags: differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, curvature

Let $b:\mathbb{R}^3 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R} $ , $b(x,y)=x_1y_1+x_2y_2-x_3y_3$ be the Minkowski innter product and let $\mathbb{H}^2=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^3:b(x,x)=-1, x_3>0\}$.
So $\mathbb{H}^2$, as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$, is the upper half of a two sheeted hyperboloid. $\mathbb{H^2}$ is a model of a hyperbolic plane (when we define what we mean by a *line* in our model and we do that by setting $l=\{x\in \mathbb{H^2}:b(n,x)=0\}$ where $n$ is a unit space-like vector in Minkowski space (i.e. $b(n,n)=1$)).

I'm interested in calculating the Gaussian curvature of our model. Book which I'm following says that every hyperbolic plane has *constant negative Gaussian curvature*.
Just by looking at the $\mathbb{H^2}\subset\mathbb{R^3}$ I see it's Gaussian curvature should be *positive*.

But ok, let's do some calculations. I parametrized $\mathbb{H^2}$ as follows:

$\varphi:\mathbb{R^2}\longrightarrow\mathbb{H^2}\varphi(u,v)=(\sinh(u)\cosh(v),\sinh(v),\cosh(u)\cosh(v)$

Using the formula for Gaussian curvature $K=\frac{eg-f^2}{EG-F^2}$, where $E,G,F$ and $e,g,f$ are coefficients of, respectively, first and second fundamental form, I got $K=\frac{1}{({1-2z^2})^2}$

But than I thought I shouldn't be using the standard inner product when calculating $E,G,F,e,g,f$.
I should use the Minkowski inner product.

So, using the same parametrization but the Minkowski inner product I got:

$E=\cosh^2(v)$, $F=0$, $G=1$.

$N=\frac{\partial_1 \times \partial_2}{\vert\vert{\partial_1 \times \partial_2}\vert\vert}=(-\sinh(u)\cosh(v),-\sinh(v),-\cosh(u)\cosh(v))$

$e=\cosh^2(v)$, $f=0$, $g=1$

So, $K=1$.

What am I doing wrong? I know I should get $K=-1$ but how? And if my idea of using Minkowski inner product is correct could someone provide intuition why?

Comment: Although the induced metric on the hyperboloid is Riemannian, you cannot casually use the same Euclidean formulas for $K$ that work in Euclidean $3$-space.

Comment: When you change something at the start, like switching from the Euclidean inner product to the Minkowski inner product, you can't just assume that the final formula of anything remains the same. What you can try to do is to start from scratch and see whether the definitions (such as for the Gauss map and the first and second fundamental forms) can be adapted to the new situation and what the resulting formulas (such as the one for Gauss curvature) become. This is a good exercise!

Comment: Your statement "I see it's Gaussian curvature should be positive" would have been true if you were restricting the Euclidean inner product $x_1 y_1 + x_2 y_2 + x_3 y_3$ to $\mathbb H^2$. But that's not what you are suppposed to do. You are instead supposed to restrict the Minkowski inner product $x_1 y_1 + x_2 y_2 - x_3 y_3$.